# unable to get DataRow with an excel datasource

Tags: c#

gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows().First());

returns null

it used to work when the source was a DataTable but when i change that to an excelDatasource it is returning null
i have tried using GetRow() method but it returns an error with  unable to cast excel source to datarow.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T429078/exceldatasource-how-to-retrieve-actual-values-in-code) support question could help you.

Comment: Ya I came across that solution earlier. But didn't work for my scenario. Thanks for the suggestion.